# Matrix fields & flexslider

Tags: expressionengine, flexslider, channel

I'm using the flexslider to create a carousel of pictures and use channel entries to populate the list items (images) that the flexslider uses to create the carousel.

Now I want to add a link to a pdf on al those list items that I have in a matrix field in the channel and that works also but only for the first list item.

Anybody knows why this is?

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="lr_press"}
            {if press_slider_switch != ""}
            {press_artikel}
            <li><a href="{press_document}" targat="_blank"><img src="{press_beeld}" alt="{title}" /></a></li>
            {/press_artikel}
            {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If your question doesn't get the attention you need here, consider posting it in expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Comment: thx for the info! http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12654/matrix-fields-flexslider